# Excecute a function for different MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute my function for each department which is active in my database.

**My departments are registered as following (table name: departments)**:

[image]

I was thinking to create WHILE. But It's not working and I think I'm not doing it the right way.

My goal is to store with this function a Day Closure with worked hours per department. How can I accomplish this?

**My script:**

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

$date = '23-10-2017';
$department = '5';

$worked_time = dayClosure($department, $date, $conn); 

function dayClosure($department, $date, $conn) {

    echo $department;
    echo $date;
    $qClosure = 'SELECT * FROM timeRegistration WHERE department IN ("'. $department .'")';
    $rClosure = mysqli_query($conn, $qClosure);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rClosure)) {
        if ($row['enddate'] == $date && $row['status'] == '3') {
            $totalWorkedTime += $row['worktime'];
        }
    }
    return $totalWorkedTime;
}

$amount_persons = 2;

$qDayClosure = 'INSERT INTO day_closures (date, department, amount_persons, worked_time) VALUES ("'. $date .'", "'. $department .'", "'. $amount_persons .'", "'. $worked_time .'")';
mysqli_query($conn, $qDayClosure);  

?>
```

**Table name: timeRegistration (In this table all time registration of each person is registered)**
[image]

[image: This is the table where the day closures will be written. I want to achieve this.]

**This is the table where the day closures will be written. I want to achieve this: (Table name: day_closures)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this query...

```
$date = '23-10-2017';
$department = '5';

function dayClosure($department, $date, $conn) {

echo $department;
echo $date;
$qClosure = 'SELECT d.name,SUM(t.worked_time) twt,t.date 
FROM departement d LEFT JOIN timeRegistration t ON d.id=t.department
WHERE t.department IN ("'. $department .'") AND t.date="'.$date.'"
GROUP BY t.date,t.department';

$rClosure = mysqli_query($conn, $qClosure);


while($row = $rClosure->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['name'].' = '.$row['twt'].' AT '.$row['date']; //This may differ based on array.
}

}
```

This will give you sum of worked_time of 23-10-2017 of each department.

Comment: how can I use this? How to ego?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/dutchquality/public_html/planning/test.php on line 22 - If I echo only the print_r (it shows only "5 23-10-2017)"

Comment: Also the table for the day closures is not the same table as where the script should take the timeregistrations. I updated my post with also the Timeregistration table. The data comes from there, and I want to create a day closure with the table which I already had included as image. A dayclosure per department with values as: date, department, amount_persons, worked_time.

Comment: Give me what you are getting by  echo "<pre>";print_r($row); and comment the second line..  echo $row['d']['name'].' = .'$row[0][ 'twt'];

Comment: Ouput: 523-10-2017

Comment: It maybe in array

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: Code Updated Again.. Works fine for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157557/discussion-between-gyandeep-sharma-and-nhatimme).